# Yii2 отображение контента в зависимости от региона

Tags: yii2

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как грамотно реализовать отображение контента в зависимости от выбранного города?

**Пример**

Есть таблица `city`:

```
id
name
default
```

Таблица `company`:

```
id
name
city_id
```

Таблица `department`:

```
id
name
company_id
city_id
```

Нужно присвоить вошедшему пользователю город (или несколько) из таблицы `city` (например в куку), вывести в нужных view select с доступными пользователю городами и построить отображение данных из таблиц на основании выбранного в select'е города.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не говорю что нужно именно так, но вот один из способов:

В контроллере формируем массив доступных городов для селекта:

```
$records = City::find()->all();
$cities = [];
foreach($records as $city) {
    $cities[$city->id] = $city->name;
}

return $this->render('/site/yourview', [
    //...
    'cities' => $city,
]);
```

На view "рисуем" select:

```
// с использованием ActiveForm
<?= $form->field($model, 'city')->dropDownList($cities); ?>

// без использования ActiveForm
<select>
<?php foreach($cities as $key => $value) { ?>
    <option value="<?=$key?>"><?=$value?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Обработку выбора option в select писать не буду. Подумайте сами как вам лучше и удобнее это сделать.
Далее:

```
//запись в куки
Yii::$app->response->cookies->add(new \yii\web\Cookie([
    'name' => 'city',
    'value' => 'Москва',
    'expire' => time() + 7776000, //90 дней
]));
```

Затем в контроллере:

```
$userCity = Yii::$app->request->cookies['city']; //чтение куки

// поиск нужных данных
$companies = Company::find()->where(['city_id' => $userCity])->all();
$departments = Department::find()->where(['city_id' => $userCity])->all();

// рендер вьюхи с данными
return $this->render('/site/view', [
    'companies' => $companies,
    'departments' => $departments
]);
```

Comment: я немного изменил свой вопрос, не могли бы вы подсказать идею, как можно реализовать его с выпадающим списком?

Comment: изменил ответ...

Comment: благодарю за ответ. `как вам лучше и удобнее это сделать` - проблема как раз в том, что я не могу понять, как передать значение select'a в модель поиска

Comment: можно в контроллере создать action и туда обычным JS Ajax-ом передавать данные и обрабатывать, можно создать модель и с помощью ActiveForm собирать данные из селекта и позже так же в action на контроллере обрабатывать. Тут много вариантов. Гугл в помощь

Comment: благодарю. реализовал с помощью штатной модели поиска.